# Why is my dojo modulePaths configuration being ignored?

Tags: javascript, module, dojo, require

I am trying to setup custom module paths in Dojo 1.6, however i cant seem to get the paths correct. I keep receiving the following error.. it seems like the path doesn't get changed..

Error

```
http://url/dojotest/dojo/myApp/base.js 404 (Not Found)
```

Directory Structure

```
/var/www/html/dojotest
   /dojo
      /dijit
      /dojo
      /dojox
   /myApp
      base.js
  index.html
```

index.html

```
<html>
<head>
   <title>Dojo Testing</title>
   <script src="dojo/dojo/dojo.js"></script>   
   <script>
   var djConfig = 
   {
      modulePaths : { 'myApp' : '../../myApp' }
   };
   dojo.require('myApp.base');
   </script>
</head>
<body>
   <div>Lala Testy test test</div>
</body>
</html>
```

base.js

```
dojo.provide('myApp.base');

console.log('you found me!');
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to set the `djConfig` *before* including the `dojo.js` script tag

```
<script>
var dojoConfig = {
    modulePaths : { 'myApp' : '../../myApp' }
};
</script>

<script src="dojo/dojo/dojo.js"></script>

<script>
dojo.require('myApp.base');
</script>
```

Comment: still true for dojo 1.8, still not easy to find in the docu *grmbl*

Comment: @cypherabe: The new async loader has additional ways to set this kind of configurations though. I highly recommend snover's [Dojo Boilerplate](https://github.com/csnover/dojo-boilerplate) if you are starting out.